# How to properly stop Twisted reactor when callback is finished

Tags: python, twisted

I am still very new to Python, but I have a grasp on the basics. I am trying to write a script that will allow me to interface with Deluge's API. Right now I am just trying to get the current download queue back, but the reactor keeps running. If I put reactor.stop() at the end of Deluge().onGetSessionState() then the reactor stops before Deluge().onGetTorrentStatus() comes back.

I'm confused on how to handle stopping the reactor when onGetSessionState gets everything it needs from onGetTorrentStatus.

```
from deluge.ui.client import client
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Deluge(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        for key, value in enumerate(args):
            self.key = value

    def getDownloadQueue(self):
        self.connect("getQueue")

    def connect(self,params):
        deluge = client.connect()
        deluge.addCallback(self.onConnect,params).addErrback(self.onConnectFail).addBoth(self.disconnect)
        reactor.run()

    def disconnect(self):
        client.disconnect()
        reactor.stop()

    def onConnect(self,result,params):
        def onGetTorrentStatus(torrentInfo):
            print torrentInfo["name"] + " " + torrentInfo["label"]

        def onGetSessionState(torrent_ids):
            # This prints the torrent_ids just fine
            print torrent_ids
            # This only works if I keep the self.disconnect() below commented out
            for id in torrent_ids:
                client.core.get_torrent_status(id, ["name","label"]).addCallback(onGetTorrentStatus)

        if params == "getQueue":
            client.core.get_session_state().addCallback(onGetSessionState)
            # self.disconnect()

    def onConnectFail(self,result):
        print "Error: %s" % result
        reactor.stop()

deluge = Deluge()
deluge.getDownloadQueue()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific issue you're hitting is that `onGetTorrentStatus` is added as a callback to multiple Deferreds (because it is added inside the loop over `torrent_ids`).

As soon as the first `get_torrent_status` Deferred gets a result, `onGetTorrentStatus` is called.  If `onGetTorrentStatus` stops the reactor then none of the other status calls get a chance to complete.

You want to wait for *all* of the `get_torrent_status` Deferreds to get their results before stopping.

`twisted.internet.defer.gatherResults` should help you with this.

You probably also want to look at `twisted.internet.task.react` which will replace your calls to *both* `reactor.run` and `reactor.stop` (you still need `gatherResults` though, or `react` won't know the correct time to call `reactor.stop` either).

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this working. I'm sure your answer is correct, I just need to do more research on Twisted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the multiple Deferreds issue and simplify your script by calling `client.core.get_torrents_status` and it will return all the current torrent id's in session and the specified status keys.